# Sequelize delete request with payload works with Postman but not with Vue Frontend implementation

Tags: sqlite, express, vue.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to send PUT and DELETE requests with my express backend to a sqlite database. Put request works fine but DELETE request always fails.

I already checked the headers within the network tab, it seems to be the right one for both (application/json)
With postman, I can easily delete entries, but with my frontend the body does not seem to be set correctly.

```
       const countryToPush = {title: countryName}
       try{
        await CountryService.post(countryToPush)
        console.log(countryName + ' added!')
       } catch(err)
       {
        console.log(err)
       }
       },
       removeFromDb: async function(countryName){
       const countryToDelete = {title: countryName}
       try{
        await CountryService.delete(countryToDelete)
        console.log(countryName + ' deleted!')
       } catch(err)
       {
        console.log(err)
       }
      }
```

This is within my vue file where I get the 'countryName' from an on click function.

```
    try {
      const country = await Country.create(req.body)
      res.send(country)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'an error has occurred trying to create the country'
      })
    }
  },
  async delete (req, res) {
    try {
      const toDelete = await Country.findOne({
        where: {
          title: req.body.title
        }
      })
      await toDelete.destroy()
      res.send(req.body.title + ' was deleted')
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'an error has occurred trying to delete the country'
      })
    }
  }
```

Whereas this is the example from my sqlite calls

Unfortunately, the DELETE request from my vue frontend always fails and gives me the defined error 500 `an error has occurred trying to delete the country.`

Any ideas what else I could try to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

`Model.delete()` is not a Sequelize function, you want to use [`Model.destroy()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-destroy).

```
await CountryService.destroy(countryToDelete)
```

Right now you are swallowing the actual error - add `console.log(err)` to your catch to see that it is probably saying `CountryService.destroy is undefined`.